# Unity Android Resolution Failed

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle-plugin

I'm currently struggling weird bug or error in **Unity3D**. Despite of only using original Google plugins, I get following error try to resolve Android dependencies. Here is error log:

```
Resolution failed

Failed to fetch the following dependencies:
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:15.0.2
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-license:15.0.2
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite-license:15.0.2
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:15.0.2
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.2
com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone-license:15.0.2
com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:15.0.2
com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base-license:15.0.2
com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:15.0.2
com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.2
com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.2
com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.2
com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive-license:15.0.2
com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:15.0.2
com.google.android.gms:play-services-games-license:15.0.2
com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:15.0.2
com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass-license:15.0.2
com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass:15.0.2
com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby-license:15.0.2
com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:15.0.2
com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:15.0.2
com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.2
com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl-license:15.0.2
com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-license:15.0.2
com.google.firebase:firebase-common-license:15.0.2
com.google.firebase:firebase-common:15.0.2
com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-license:15.0.2
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-license:15.0.2


UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Google.Logger:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.<ResolveUnsafe>c__AnonStorey2:<>m__1()
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:PumpUpdateQueue()
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions() (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\EditorApplication.cs:183)

(Filename: C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/EditorApplication.cs Line: 183)
```

Here is list of my plugins:

- Google Play Games 0.9.50: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity
- Google Mobile Ads 3.13.1: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/releases
- Firebase Unity SDK 4.5.2: https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup
- Google Analytics: https://github.com/googleanalytics/google-analytics-plugin-for-unity

According to log, 15.0.2 couldn't found but I'm currently using v15.0.2 libraries in Android Studio. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by using the PlayServicesResolver and just re-importing everything.

Answer (score 2):

Just to make it clear I fixed it this way :

1. Make a backup of what's inside `Assets/Plugins/Android` and delete the **entire folder** (the backup is for if you deleted some files not related with the Android Resolver)
2. Restart Unity Editor
3. Do a resolution again (at `Assets > External Dependency Manager > Android Resolver > Resolve` or `Assets > Play Services Resolver > Android Resolver > Resolve` depending on your version)

Now the resolution should succeed.